# (Laravel) How to show data list and data detail in one view

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, voyager

I have a view with data list and data detail in one view. I'm trying to show both of them but I have no idea how. You can see the code below

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="theSidebar" class="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="theGrid" class="main">
        <section class="grid">

<!-- /posts --> 
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <a class="grid__item" href="#">
                <h2 class="title title--preview">{{$post->title}}</h2>
                <span class="category">{{$post->title}}</span>
                <div class="loader"></div>
                <div class="meta meta--preview">
                    <img class="meta__avatar" src="{{ Voyager::image( $post->image ) }}" alt="{{$post->title}}" /> 
                    <span class="meta__date"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>{{$post->created_at->format('m-d-Y')}}</span>
                    <span class="meta__reading-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{$post->created_at->format('H-i')}}</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            @endforeach
<!-- /end post -->

        </section>

<!-- /post content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="scroll-wrap">
                <article class="content__item">
                    <span class="category category--full">{{$post->title}}</span>
                    <h2 class="title title--full">{{$post->title}}</h2>
                    <div class="meta meta--full">
                        <img class="meta__avatar" src="{{ Voyager::image( $post->image ) }}" alt="{{$post->title}}" />
                        <span class="meta__author">{{$post->title}}</span>
                        <span class="meta__date"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>{{$post->created_at}}</span>
                        <span class="meta__reading-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{$post->created_at->format('m/d/Y')}}</span>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
            <button class="close-button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i><span>Close</span></button>
        </section>
<!-- /end post content-->

    </div>
</div><!-- /container -->
```

My question is how to do show the post detail in 'post content section'. Am I have to do some loop again to get the data? 
Thank you

Comment: try reading about Laravel Relationships

Answer (score 0):

Each post in the list contains an ID, so you have to call based on the ID to display content of that particular post.

' < a href="{{ route('post.show', ['id' => $post['id']]) }}" type="button"

class="btn">View < /a> '

You should explore ajax if you want to view post details without loading the page.

Comment: That's the problem too, each post doesn't have any ID. It was working in wordpress, but I need to implement it using Voyager Laravel and I have no idea to do it

Comment: since you dont have any ID, I suggest you use table with modal so can view details on expanding the list or pop up. Similar to this example: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html